# bower or npm private project dependencies

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, npm, bower

when starting a new project and with that a your projects dependency list as I understand you start with `bower init` or `npm init`. But when doing that it ask for things like main npm-> entry point, and for bower-> ignore lists, main file. But for a private project which I am not planning to share on either of their registries those are not needed. And in other projects for exmpl. angular-seed project bower.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-loader": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.0",
    "html5-boilerplate": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

there are no ignore lists and main files. So the question is, if I want to start a new project after generating a bower.json or package.json file I should just delete the extra properties from the json? Or is there an extra command which would prevent adding those extra lines?

Comment: If you delete them, NPM warns you that the expected fields are missing. Other than that, I don't remember any side effects.

Comment: By why those fields do not exists in other projects? like the one mentioned. Do they write them manually?

Comment: Most likely they do. `npm init` creates some extra fields. If some are missing (description or so) it will show a warning in the console. Only name and version are required.